# PHP удаление текста

Tags: php, html, файлы, строки

Всем привет, возник такой вопрос , есть свой скрипт который заносит данные в файл после каждого ображения к нему , данные в основном состоят из формы.
Вопрос , возможно ли как - то помимо `str_replace` удалить форму из содержимого файла , если эта форма там не одна а есть еще несколько.

```
<form method="POST" action="creator.php">

  <div class="inpt">
    Tour Text
  </div>
  <div class="inp">
    <input type="text" name="content36" size="40" value="<?php $cfile = 'content/content36.txt';$cont = file_get_contents($cfile); echo $cont;?>" style="text-align:center;">
  </div>

  <div class="inpt">
    Tour Text
  </div>

  <div class="inp">
    <textarea name="content37" rows="30" cols="100" style="resize:none;">
      <?php $cfile='content/content37.txt' ;$cont=f ile_get_contents($cfile); echo $cont; ?>
    </textarea>
  </div>



  <div class="inp">
    <input type="submit" value="Change Content">
  </div>
```

Нужно удалять подобные формы , не заменяя других, есть ли способ помимо `str_replace` ?

Comment: есть вообще не писать эту форму в фаил

Comment: спасибо , ваш ответ сильно помог решить вопрос

Comment: Вы хотите удалять выборочно данные, но данные могут дублироваться и ничем не отличатся . Следовательно нужно сделать так, что бы данные стали уникальными . Как вариант добавить признак "время" и его анализировать по каким либо условиям.

Comment: спасибо большое , решил вопрос созданием для каждой формы отдельного файла , так легче и удобнее для редактирования